# PowerShell - Send-MailMessage with OCI EmailDelivery - Intermittent

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I've been using the below script to send email and sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. I'm not sure exactly why it is intermittent and with this error:"

ERROR: The smtp server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required"

This is the script I'm using:

By the way, I want to send emails via SMTP using PowerShell from an instance I built using OCI's Email Delivery service, and the instance is running Windows Server 2019.

`$smtpServer = "smtp.email.ap-tokyo-1.oci.oraclecloud.com"`
`$smtpPort = 587`
`$password = "***********************"`
`$from = "alerts@test.com"`
`$to = "recipient@domain.com"`
`$subject = "OCI EmailDelivery Test Email"`
`$body = "OCI EmailDelivery Test Email"`
`$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, $smtpPort)`
`$smtp.EnableSsl = $true`
`$smtp.Credentials = new-object Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)`
`$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage`
`$msg.From = $from`
`$msg.To.Add($to)`
`$msg.CC.Add($cc)`
`$msg.Subject = $subject`
`$smtp.Send($msg)`
`$msg.Body = $body`